# Add box at the end of environment on the footer

Tags: fancyhdr, box

Here's my current environment:

```latex
\documentclass{report}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                                              %
%                                Preamble Stuff                                %
%                                                                              %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\author{\hmwkAuthorName}

\fancyhead[L]{\hmwkAuthorName}
\fancyhead[C]{\hmwkClass: \hmwkTitle: \hmwkClassInstructorShortName}
\fancyhead[R]{\firstxmark}
\fancyfoot[L]{\lastxmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.4pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.4pt}

\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\textbf{\large Part \Alph{partCounter}}\stepcounter{partCounter}\\}

\newcounter{countitems}
\newcounter{nextitemizecount}
\newcommand{\setupcountitems}{%
  \stepcounter{nextitemizecount}%
  \setcounter{countitems}{0}%
  \preto\item{\stepcounter{countitems}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\computecountitems}{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\number\c@countitems}%
}
\newcommand{\nextitemizecount}{%
  \getrefnumber{countitems@\number\c@nextitemizecount}%
}
\newcommand{\previtemizecount}{%
  \getrefnumber{countitems@\number\numexpr\value{nextitemizecount}-1\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{AutoMultiColItemize}{%
  \ifnumcomp{\nextitemizecount}{>}{3}{\begin{multicols}{2}}{}%
    \setupcountitems\begin{itemize}}%
    {\end{itemize}%
  \unskip\computecountitems\ifnumcomp{\previtemizecount}{>}{3}{\end{multicols}}{}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcounter{partCounter}
\newcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}
\setcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}{1}
\newcounter{homeworkSolutionCounter}
\setcounter{homeworkSolutionCounter}{1}
\nobreak\extramarks{Problem \arabic{homeworkProblemCounter}}{}\nobreak{}

\newcommand{\enterProblemHeader}[1]{
  \nobreak\extramarks{}{
    Problem \arabic{#1} continued on next page \ldots
  }\nobreak{}
  \nobreak\extramarks{
    Problem \arabic{#1} (continued)
  }{
    Problem \arabic{#1} continued on next page \ldots
  }\nobreak{}
}

\newcommand{\exitProblemHeader}[1]{
  \nobreak\extramarks{
    Problem \arabic{#1} (continued)
  }{
    Problem \arabic{#1} continued on next page\ldots
  }\nobreak{}
  \stepcounter{#1}
  \nobreak\extramarks{
    Problem \arabic{#1}
  }{}\nobreak{}
}

\newenvironment{solution}[1][-1]{
  \ifnum#1>0
    \setcounter{homeworkSolutionCounter}{#1}
  \fi
  \section{Solution \arabic{homeworkSolutionCounter}}
  \setcounter{partCounter}{1}
  \enterProblemHeader{homeworkSolutionCounter}
}{
  \exitProblemHeader{homeworkSolutionCounter}
}

\newenvironment{problem}[1][-1]{
  \ifnum#1>0
    \setcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}{#1}
  \fi
  \section{Problem \arabic{homeworkProblemCounter}}
  \setcounter{partCounter}{1}
  \enterProblemHeader{homeworkProblemCounter}
}{
  \exitProblemHeader{homeworkProblemCounter}
}

\title{
  \vspace{2in}
  \textmd{\textmd{\textbf{\hmwkClass:\ \hmwkTitle}}}\\
  \normalsize\vspace{0.1in}\small{Due\ on\ \hmwkDueDate\ at \hmwkDueTime}\\
  \vspace{0.1in}\large{\textit{\hmwkClassInstructor\ \hmwkClassTime}}
  \vspace{3in}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                                              %
%                                Main Document                                 %
%                                                                              %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\hmwkTitle}{Title}
\newcommand{\hmwkDueDate}{Date}

\newcommand{\hmwkDueTime}{Time}
\newcommand{\hmwkClass}{Course}
\newcommand{\hmwkClassTime}{Time}
\newcommand{\hmwkClassInstructor}{Professor}
\newcommand{\hmwkClassInstructorShortName}{Professor}
\newcommand{\hmwkAuthorName}{\textbf{Student}}

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \maketitle

  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \setcounter{page}{1}

  \begin{problem}
    problem
  \end{problem}
  \begin{solution}
    solution
  \end{solution}

  \newpage

  \begin{problem}
    problem
  \end{problem}
  \begin{solution}
    solution
  \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

Which creates a nice assignment template. But, I would like to add a box to the footer when I complete the solution environment. For example, sometimes my solutions may go over 5 pages and I only want a box on the last (5th) page for my professor to put in how many points I got out of the total possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a new pagestyle `boxfooter` that puts a box in the footer, and at the end of `solution` add `\thispagestyle{boxfooter}`. There might be some cases where the page breaking algorithm puts the thing on the wrong page, and then a solution with marks would be necessary. But I would go with this solution first.

I only give the relevant code parts.

```
\fancyhead[L]{\hmwkAuthorName}
\fancyhead[C]{\hmwkClass: \hmwkTitle: \hmwkClassInstructorShortName}
\fancyhead[R]{\firstxmark}
\fancyfoot[L]{\lastxmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\fancyfoot[R]{} % <<<<<< default

\fancypagestyle{boxfooter}{
  \fancyfoot[R]{\setlength\unitlength{1cm}
    \begin{picture}(0,0)
      \put(-1,-0.7){\framebox(1,1)}
    \end{picture}}
}
```

```
\newenvironment{solution}[1][-1]{
  \ifnum#1>0
    \setcounter{homeworkSolutionCounter}{#1}
  \fi
  \section{Solution \arabic{homeworkSolutionCounter}}
  \setcounter{partCounter}{1}
  \enterProblemHeader{homeworkSolutionCounter}
}{
  \exitProblemHeader{homeworkSolutionCounter}
  \thispagestyle{boxfooter}% <<<<<< added
}
```

The size of the box can be changed by changing `\unitlength`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

With adding `amsthm` and `\qed` you can get the desired output, and the MWE is:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsthm}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                                              %
%                                Preamble Stuff                                %
%                                                                              %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\usepackage{extramarks}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}

\author{\hmwkAuthorName}

\fancyhead[L]{\hmwkAuthorName}
\fancyhead[C]{\hmwkClass: \hmwkTitle: \hmwkClassInstructorShortName}
\fancyhead[R]{\firstxmark}
\fancyfoot[L]{\lastxmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0.4pt}
\renewcommand\footrulewidth{0.4pt}

\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\textbf{\large Part \Alph{partCounter}}\stepcounter{partCounter}\\}

\newcounter{countitems}
\newcounter{nextitemizecount}
\newcommand{\setupcountitems}{%
  \stepcounter{nextitemizecount}%
  \setcounter{countitems}{0}%
  \preto\item{\stepcounter{countitems}}%
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\computecountitems}{%
  \edef\@currentlabel{\number\c@countitems}%
}
\newcommand{\nextitemizecount}{%
  \getrefnumber{countitems@\number\c@nextitemizecount}%
}
\newcommand{\previtemizecount}{%
  \getrefnumber{countitems@\number\numexpr\value{nextitemizecount}-1\relax}%
}
\makeatother

\newenvironment{AutoMultiColItemize}{%
  \ifnumcomp{\nextitemizecount}{>}{3}{\begin{multicols}{2}}{}%
    \setupcountitems\begin{itemize}}%
    {\end{itemize}%
  \unskip\computecountitems\ifnumcomp{\previtemizecount}{>}{3}{\end{multicols}}{}}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{0}
\newcounter{partCounter}
\newcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}
\setcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}{1}
\newcounter{homeworkSolutionCounter}
\setcounter{homeworkSolutionCounter}{1}
\nobreak\extramarks{Problem \arabic{homeworkProblemCounter}}{}\nobreak{}

\newcommand{\enterProblemHeader}[1]{
  \nobreak\extramarks{}{
    Problem \arabic{#1} continued on next page \ldots
  }\nobreak{}
  \nobreak\extramarks{
    Problem \arabic{#1} (continued)
  }{
    Problem \arabic{#1} continued on next page \ldots
  }\nobreak{}
}

\newcommand{\exitProblemHeader}[1]{
  \nobreak\extramarks{
    Problem \arabic{#1} (continued)
  }{
    Problem \arabic{#1} continued on next page\ldots
  }\nobreak{}
  \stepcounter{#1}
  \nobreak\extramarks{
    Problem \arabic{#1}
  }{}\nobreak{}
}

\newenvironment{solution}[1][-1]{
  \ifnum#1>0
    \setcounter{homeworkSolutionCounter}{#1}
  \fi
  \section{Solution \arabic{homeworkSolutionCounter}}
  \setcounter{partCounter}{1}
  \enterProblemHeader{homeworkSolutionCounter}
}{
\qed  \exitProblemHeader{homeworkSolutionCounter}
}

\newenvironment{problem}[1][-1]{
  \ifnum#1>0
    \setcounter{homeworkProblemCounter}{#1}
  \fi
  \section{Problem \arabic{homeworkProblemCounter}}
  \setcounter{partCounter}{1}
  \enterProblemHeader{homeworkProblemCounter}
}{
  \exitProblemHeader{homeworkProblemCounter}
}

\title{
  \vspace{2in}
  \textmd{\textmd{\textbf{\hmwkClass:\ \hmwkTitle}}}\\
  \normalsize\vspace{0.1in}\small{Due\ on\ \hmwkDueDate\ at \hmwkDueTime}\\
  \vspace{0.1in}\large{\textit{\hmwkClassInstructor\ \hmwkClassTime}}
  \vspace{3in}
}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%                                                                              %
%                                Main Document                                 %
%                                                                              %
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\newcommand{\hmwkTitle}{Title}
\newcommand{\hmwkDueDate}{Date}

\newcommand{\hmwkDueTime}{Time}
\newcommand{\hmwkClass}{Course}
\newcommand{\hmwkClassTime}{Time}
\newcommand{\hmwkClassInstructor}{Professor}
\newcommand{\hmwkClassInstructorShortName}{Professor}
\newcommand{\hmwkAuthorName}{\textbf{Student}}

\begin{document}
  \pagestyle{empty}
  \maketitle

  \pagestyle{fancy}
  \setcounter{page}{1}

  \begin{problem}
    problem
  \end{problem}
  \begin{solution}
    solution
  \end{solution}

  \newpage

  \begin{problem}
    problem
  \end{problem}
  \begin{solution}
    solution
  \end{solution}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Comment: I would like to have the box in the footer next to the page number.